# How to set generated string as a unique session key?

Tags: javascript, php, session

I have a website that creates a session when a user logs in, but the sessions are just the email & username, which works fine for customers that create an account, but I want to generate a unique session key for users that *dont* want to signup/login, the reason is because currently if a user is not logged in and they add an item to the checkout page, the item will be visible to every customer who is not logged in, so I would like to create a session based on a unique string so that there are no conflicts for customers who dont want to signup/sign-in.

The problem is that when I redirect to the test.php page it cant find the session key.

Here is my session file that generates the unique key..

```
<?php
 session_start();

 $_SESSION['sessionKey'] = $randomString;

 if(!isset($_SESSION['sessionKey']))
 {

 function generateRandomString($length = 64) {
   $characters = '0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ';
   $charactersLength = strlen($characters);
   $randomString = '';
   for ($i = 0; $i < $length; $i++) {
      $randomString .= $characters[rand(0, $charactersLength - 1)];
   }
   return $randomString;
   }
   echo generateRandomString();
   }
   ?>

   <br><br>
   <a href="test.php">Go to test page</a>
```

and then my test.php page...

```
<?php
 session_start();

 if(!isset($_SESSION['sessionKey']))
 {
  echo "cant find unique session key";
 } else {
  echo $_SESSION['sessionKey'];
 }
 ?>
```

Comment: Your not calling the function generateRandomString on line 4; your $_SESSION is empty in first page.

Comment: when I call on line 4 I get "call to undefined function generateRandomString"

Comment: Yes your function was in the local scope not on global scope that was the reason that you were not able to access it. I rewrote your code.

Comment: The problem is that on line 4, you have `$_SESSION['sessionKey'] = $randomString;`. But `$randomString` does not exist in this location. You never declared it. `if(!isset($_SESSION['sessionKey']))` this will always return false because you set `$_SESSION['sessionKey']` on line 4, even though you never give it any value. Hence `generateRandomString();` is undefined, since it's never declared

Comment: Small tip: Use `if(empty($variable))` instead of `if(!isset($variable)`. The `empty()` method will not only check if a variable exists, it'll also check if it has a value. It's much more reliable than `isset` because of this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will keep the unique session even you visit the first page again.

```
session_start();

 if(!isset($_SESSION['sessionKey']))  {
    $_SESSION['sessionKey'] = generateRandomString();
   }

function generateRandomString($length = 64) {
   $characters = '0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ';
   $charactersLength = strlen($characters);
   $randomString = '';
   for ($i = 0; $i < $length; $i++) {
      $randomString .= $characters[rand(0, $charactersLength - 1)];
   }
   return $randomString;
}

echo $_SESSION['sessionKey'];
```

Comment: How will this generate unique key everytime? Can it not duplicate?

Comment: Whenever you visit the page with this code it will generate a unique code and will keep it until you close the browser. if you want to generate a unique code on each visit just remove the first if statement and put this line of code in the top.  $_SESSION['sessionKey'] = generateRandomString();

Answer (score 0):

try this code:

```
<?php
    session_start();

    
    function generateRandomString($length = 64) {
        $characters = '0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ';
        $charactersLength = strlen($characters);
        $randomString = '';
        for ($i = 0; $i < $length; $i++) {
            $randomString .= $characters[rand(0, $charactersLength - 1)];
        }
        return $randomString;
    }

    if(!isset($_SESSION['sessionKey']))
    {
        $_SESSION['sessionKey'] = generateRandomString();
        echo $_SESSION['sessionKey'];
    }

   ?>

   <br><br>
   <a href="test.php">Go to test page</a>
```

Comment: I am receiving "call to undefined function generateRandomString"

Comment: i have change the code please try again, and let me know if it is working now

Comment: Welcome to SO! 
Can you explain your answer?
Refer to [How do I write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) guidline to improve your contribution.